# Mediaplayer : pause called in state 1 - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a MediaPlayer button in the ActionBar, wherein it is playing automatically when the app started and when I clicked it should be off. The problem now is that the sound is not playing and when I click the button there is an error in logcat saying...

UPDATED LOGCAT.

```
12-18 19:04:57.812: E/MediaPlayer(5673): attachNewPlayer called in state 32
```

Here is the code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private MediaPlayer mp;
Item btnplay;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isPlaying=false;//when the media file playing is completed isPlaying=false; is must
}
});
play(null);//you are calling play by launching
}

//inflate items in actionbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

boolean isPlaying = false;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    return true;
}
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btnplay) //whatever you named in xml
    {
        play(item);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

public void play(MenuItem menuItem) {

if (!isPlaying) {
try
{
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("caketown.mp3"); 
    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();//play sound
}
catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
isPlaying = true;
}
else if (isPlaying) {
mp.pause();
isPlaying = false;
}
}
```

Here is the menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.xxx.MainActivity" >

<item
android:id="@+id/btnplay"
android:title=""
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_volume_on"
android:onClick="play"
android:showAsAction="always"/>   
<menu>
```

Please help me. I'm just new here. :(

Comment: by default it goes to pause function because yo wrote as else if (isPlaying) { pause the audio and by your careless you initialze as  true

Comment: i have editedt my code please change your elseif and one more please donte make such silly mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Please initialize `mp = new MediaPlayer();` in your `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play(null);//you are calling play by launching
    }
```

2.change it to  `boolean isPlaying = false;` because when app start it set as `boolean isPlaying = false` so it will play the audio and again you click on it for pause it will work as per your code

3.change this `else if`

```
else if (isPlaying) {
mp.pause();
isPlaying=false;
}
```

4.change this function too

```
public void play(MenuItem menuItem) {

        if (!isPlaying && !isPaused) {

        try {
            if (mp == null) {
                // mp.release();
                // mp.reset();
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets()
                        .openFd("caketown.mp3");
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                        afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isPlaying = false;// when the media file playing is completed
                        isPaused = false;
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "play completed",
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // isPlaying=false; is must
                    }
                });
            }
            mp.start();// play sound
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        isPlaying = true;

        } else if (isPlaying) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "play paused",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mp.pause();
            isPlaying = false;
            isPaused = true;
            length = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // and for resuming the player from the position where it stopped
            // lately is done by:

        } else if (isPaused) {
            mp.seekTo(length);
            mp.start();
            isPlaying = true;
            isPaused = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this but the sound is not playing automatically, it played when i clicked the button and when I clicked it again the sound is playing again instead of being off. To be precise the sound is overlapping the sound. :\

Comment: I'm so sorry. But its just the same, it is not playing automatically, pause and the sounds are overlapping.

Comment: The sound is not starting auto, it played when I click and pause when i click it again, but when I click it again to play, the sound never played.

Comment: The auto work now, only the pause is not working, when I click, the  sound just overlapped.

Comment: I'm sorry, the sound is not overlapping, the pause is working but when i click to play again an error in logcat occurred. I've also updated the logcat.

Comment: declare this too private boolean isPaused=false;
 private int length;

Comment: so happy to help others !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize `isPlaying` to false to get your conditional working.
2. Initialize `MediaPlayer` only once to to get the stop/pause working instead of overlapping sounds. That is, move the `mp = new MediaPlayer();` to `onCreate()` for example.

Comment: I tried it, overlapping has gone but it does not automatically play the sound and the pause is not working.